# How to make all values unselectabled of a multiple select when one is selected with jQuery/Javascript:

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, multi-select, jquery-ui-multiselect

I have a **dynamic form using Ajax and jQuery** on my Symfony project.

I have a *multiple select*. I would like in this multiple select, when I choose **the value id 7 (which is "outside")**, all other value are unselectabled.

Here's the code for the script in my twig view:

```
function checkOption(obj) {
        var select = document.getElementById("mySpace_databasebundle_zonestechnique_batiments");
        select.disabled = obj.value == "7";
      }
```

And this is the form code in my twig view. Just know that I'am using a collection, i.e. a formType of Symfony Form to make this form:

```
<div>
                {{ form_label(form.categorieszonestechnique, "Categorie(s) de la zone technique:", {'label_attr': {'class': 'control-label'}}) }}
                {{ form_errors(form.categorieszonestechnique) }}
                {{ form_widget(form.categorieszonestechnique, {'attr': {'class': 'selectpicker categories', 'onChange': 'checkOption(this)'}}) }}
              </div>

              <div>
                {{ form_label(form.batiments, "Appartenant au bâtiment:", {'label_attr': {'class': 'control-label'}}) }}
                {{ form_errors(form.batiments) }}
                {{ form_widget(form.batiments, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'option selected': '--choose abâtiment--'}}) }}
              </div>
```

So when I selected the option 7, i-e "outside", I would like to make all other value of the multiple select unselectabled. Then make a default value (null value) to the following field for the select tag of "batiments".

The **id** for the *multiple select (selectpicker)* is `mySpace_databasebundle_zonestechnique_categorieszonestechnique` and the **id** for *the select tag of batiments* is `mySpace_databasebundle_zonestechnique_batiments`.

**Someone know how to make all other values of my multiple select unselectable, then put a null value to the following fields, i.e. the select tag for batiments.**

Comment: Which elements you want to unselect like is it check box or radio button or something else or combination ?

Comment: @Bhavikvora in fact I would like to make all other value of my multi select unselectable if users choose the value "outside", then make the next field disable which is a select tag.

Comment: you can do call this $("input").prop('disabled', true); it will disable all the input fields of the form.

Comment: @Bhavikvora I have not the code with me, but I'll try your suggestion quickly. Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 function lock() {
   $("input").prop('disabled', true);
   $("select").prop('disabled', true);
};


 function unlock() {
   $("input").prop('disabled', false);
   $("select").prop('disabled', false);
};
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" id="pizza" name="pizza" value="yes"><br/>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="Yes">
  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="No"><br/>
  <select id="pizza_kind">
    <option>(choose one)</option>
    <option value="margaritha">Margaritha</option>
    <option value="hawai">Hawai</option>
  </select><br/>
      <select id="pizza_kind1">
    <option>(choose one)</option>
    <option value="margaritha">Margaritha</option>
    <option value="hawai">Hawai</option>
  </select><br/>
 <button name="freez" onClick="lock()">Lock</button>
  <button name="freez" onClick="unlock()">Unlock</button>
</form>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I think this is what I understand from your explanation. If its not what you want then let me know